# Integrating zeppelin with custom web application

Tags: web-applications, jupyter, apache-zeppelin

We are planning to integrate zeppelin notebook functionalities in our custom web application. We can see it has back end APIs to handle the zeppelin related functionalities (creation of notebook, modify notebook, etc..) but there is no straight forward way to integrate the zeppelin UI within the custom application. We can asses that if we have to do that, we need to get the zeppelin source code and make the necessary changes for the authentication at least. And there could be other changes too.

Has anyone tried to integrate zeppelin directly with in their custom custom application?

Also, would jupyter be a good alternative in this scenario?

Comment: Hi, Zeppelin 0.8.0(SNAPSHOT) introduced new extensional features called spell. You can extend Zeppelin UI using it. Here is an example. https://github.com/Submersible/zeppelin-toc-spell You will send API for your backend (if CORS is enabled of course)

Answer (score 2):

You can create iframe or similar,You will get your required component by passing proper parameter

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/other_features/publishing_paragraphs.html

:/#/notebook/2B3QSZTKR/paragraph/...?asIframe" height="" width="" >